# Setting Textbox values which has focus in C# Winforms

Tags: c#, winforms, focus

I have numeric buttons which when pressed display the number in different text boxes. Now my problem is that i want check which textbox has focus so that the number pressed will be entered in that textbox. 
My Code:

```
private void btn_one_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt_one.Focused==true)
    {
        txt_one.Text += btn_one.Text;
    } 
    else if (txt_two.Focused==true)
    {
        txt_two.Text += btn_one.Text;
    }
}
```

Now my problem is that the above code is not working what is wrong and what will be the solution? I even used something like this

```
private void btn_one_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (txt_one.Focus()==true)
    {
        txt_one.Text += btn_one.Text; 
    }
    else if (txt_two.Focus()=true)
    {
        txt_two.Text += btn_one.Text;
    }
}
```

In both the above cases the text is entered in both the text boxes. Any solutions.

Comment: You didn't really ask a question. Is something not working?

Comment: a screenshot of your form and a actual question would help

Comment: Show your Work.. Can't able to get the Point.

Comment: I have update my question. Now is it clear or i will have to show the screen shot?

Comment: Focus is an imperative method.  You are calling the method and then querying the result of the operation!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is a little tricky (with my experience dealing with `Enter, Focus, LostFocus, Leave` events, all these things sometimes make your head ache a lot and you should avoid dealing with them if possible), at the time you click your `Button`, the current `Focused` control you can know is exactly the `Button` (`ActiveControl` is one short way to access it). So the solution is we have to record the track of focused `TextBox`, hold it in a reference and use it when needed. In fact if the control other than one of your `TextBoxes` is focused, we have to reset the variable `lastFocused` to null:

```
TextBox lastFocused;
//Enter event handler for all your TextBoxes
private void TextBoxes_Enter(object sender, EventArgs e){
  lastFocused = sender as TextBox;
}
//Click event handler for your button
private void btn_one_Click(object sender, EventArgs e){
  if(lastFocused != null) lastFocused.Text += btn_one.Text;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer @King King but the above code is not working.

Comment: @ROM do you know how to register the `Enter` event handler for **all** your textboxes?

Comment: @KingKing You're right, ActiveControl obviously is the button which was just clicked. I deleted my answer.